# How to plot implicit region that contains Solve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Suppose that I have a complicated function `F(a,x,y)` and I want to plot the 2D region of `(x,y)` points such that `F(a,x,y)=0` has a solution. How would that be possible in mathematica?

I would think that such a plot requires something on the lines of `ImplicitRegion[Solve[F[a,x,y]==0,a],{x,y}]` (of course, this code won't work).

EDIT:
A simple example would be something like `F[a,x,y]:=a^2 +x`. Then `F[a,x,y]==0` would only have a solution if `x<=0` (assuming `a,x,y` are all `Reals`) and then I would like to plot the region `x<=0` (with something like `RegionPlot`)

Comment: Thank you for adding an example. I'm afraid that I am still confused though. In your case of $F=a^2+x$, then $F=0$ is not satisfied by any value of $x<0$, but instead by exactly one value of $x$, i.e. $x=-a^2$, for each value of $a$. That's not a region, is it? Perhaps we really do need to see the complicated function.

Comment: @MarcoB So if $x=-1,y=0$, then `Solve[F[a,x,y]==0,a,Reals]` returns a solution, namely $a=\pm 1$. Therefore, in my $(x,y)$ plot, the point $(x,y)=(-1,0)$ should be my colored region. If $x=1,y=0$, then `Solve[F[a,x,y]==0,a,Reals]` does not return a solution and thus in my $(x,y)$ plot, the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$ should NOT be my colored region. Repeat this thought process for all conceivable $(x,y)$ points and then we obtain a region

Answer (score 1):

Get a fast impression e.g. for `a^2 + x - y^2 == 0` with

```
ContourPlot3D[a^2 + x - y^2 == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {a, -4, 4}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, a}, a], Mesh -> {Range[-3, 3]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
reg = Resolve[Exists[a, x^2 + a^2 - y == 0], Reals] //
  ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] &
(*  ImplicitRegion[x^2 - y <= 0, {x, y}]  *)

RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image]

Of course, transcendental equations are not always possible for solvers to solve.  And high-degree equations can be a challenge, too.